# Groovy 3 - Why does it require JDK9 to build but allows you to run with JRE8?

Tags: groovy, memory-management, java-8

If you look at the Groovy 3 release notes here: https://groovy-lang.org/releasenotes/groovy-3.0.html#Groovy3.0releasenotes-JdkRequirements

It states

> Groovy 3.0 requires JDK9+ to build and JDK8 is the minimum version of the JRE that we support.

Does anyone know why JDK9 is required to build Groovy 3 apps? We missed that requirement and have been building our Groovy 3 app with JDK8 and it compiles and runs. However, we are seeing some new production behavior with memory where it seems memory is used up more aggressively on heavier API calls.

I've Googled this extensively but have come up empty on why a JDK9 build is a requirement.

Comment: Isn't it a better question for the maintainer of groovy?

Comment: I'm voting to close this as opinion-based because the Groovy maintainer(s) would need to explain what they mean by that, as Jens' stated above. This is logically a contradictory statement; if they support JDK8, then JDK9+ is not actually required. Most likely they accidentally swapped the two and meant requires JDK8+ to build but they only support JDK9+... but again, only they can answer what they meant.

Comment: I think that's if you want to build groovy itself

Comment: @TylerH JDK9 can compile to Java 8 byte code so it might not be contradictory. Perhaps Groovy 3 needs something from JDK9 at build time but has no problem compiling down to Java 8 byte code.

Comment: @rogiller But didn't you say in your question that you compiled it using JDK8? So either way the "requires JDK9+ to build" is incorrect.